# Only read sqllite database once when it's updated, not every time when i start the application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to read the database when it's updated not every time when i start the android application.
I'm using sqlLite as my backend and CSV file contains Geolocation of the users so it's take a time to read and load the entire database..I want to reduce that time.

Comment: Reading a file takes lot of time than reading from database especially when you have lot of data in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag in shared preferences and set it every time you update data in your database and reset it every time you completely red your database. Every time you open your app check for this flag and if it is set then read database.

See this to know about shared preferences

[Android Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)